# Android Studio: Cannot resolve symbol 'activity_profile'

Tags: java, android, android-activity

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_goals) {
        startActivity(new Intent(activity_profile.this, activity_goals.class));

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_timetable) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_history) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_tracking) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_matchmaker) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Im getting the error Cannot resolve symbol 'activity_profile'on activity_profile and activity_goals while trying to make a side navigation bar button clicks move between activities.

Comment: `activity_profile`... are you sure that it's the name of one of your activities ?

Comment: Please post your error log.

Comment: Are you sure that 'activity_profile and activity_goals are names of java files of activities? If yes please post the complete code of this class here.

Comment: They are the name of the activity xml files, I need to use the Java file name?

Comment: Yes of course. You have to use Java file names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of the Intent constructor you're using should be a context. So activity_profile should be the name of the Java activity that you're writing this code in.